# Drawing player in-between Tiled .json parsed Layers

Tags: json, layer, tiled

Hello world for the first time famed stack overflow!

I am parsing a Tiled-made .json map(just a test) from [Reading JSON Tiled map editor file and displaying to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667588/reading-json-tiled-map-editor-file-and-displaying-to-canvas)

I don't fully understand the renderLayer function, and if advisable will open a new question on that.  From my rough understanding it renders each layer by tile and pushes to the final "scene" img that will be drawn.

My question specifically is how to draw a "player" object between layers.  I have a Top, Middle, and Bottom layer. The middle layer is empty and where I intend to draw the player in order to add depth. I don't know where in the code to add my player update function, and I also feel like having a player update function inside the map rendering is not very OOP..

In comments is how I can get the layer name, and I have a player update function that will handle drawing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions\explanation.

Code for the rendering the map:

```
$(function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');

scene = {
  layers: [],
  renderLayer: function(layer) {

 /*
  if(layer.name == "Middle"){
    player.update();
  }
  */

  if (layer.type !== "tilelayer" || !layer.opacity) { return; }

  var s = c.canvas.cloneNode(),
      size = scene.data.tilewidth;
  s = s.getContext("2d");

  if (scene.layers.length < scene.data.layers.length) {
    layer.data.forEach(function(tile_idx, i) {
      if (!tile_idx) { return; }

      var img_x, img_y, s_x, s_y,
          tile = scene.data.tilesets[0];

      tile_idx--;
      img_x = (tile_idx % (tile.imagewidth / size)) * size;
      img_y = ~~(tile_idx / (tile.imagewidth / size)) * size;
      s_x = (i % layer.width) * size;
      s_y = ~~(i / layer.width) * size;
      s.drawImage(scene.tileset, img_x, img_y, size, size, s_x, s_y, size, size);
    });
    scene.layers.push(s.canvas.toDataURL());
    c.drawImage(s.canvas, 0, 0);
  }else {
    scene.layers.forEach(function(src) {
        //console.log(scene);
      var i = $("<img />", { src: src })[0];
      c.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
    });
  }
},
renderLayers: function(layers) {
  layers = Array.isArray(layers) ? layers : this.data.layers;
  layers.forEach(this.renderLayer);
},
loadTileset: function(json) {
  this.data = json;
  this.tileset = $("<img />", { src: json.tilesets[0].image })[0]
  this.tileset.onload = $.proxy(this.renderLayers, this);
},
load: function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "map.json",
    dataType: "text json"
  }).done($.proxy(this.loadTileset, this));
}
};
scene.load();
});

renderMap = function(){
  scene.renderLayers();
}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific, don't post link to your github project, because nobody is going to review all your code. Post your code in question here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited and tried to explain more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is right.
I suggest to draw each layer separately. With this you can draw your Player between specified layers and you also have more control over visibilty.

As you might know, in tiled you can add several layers. Load them separately in your game and draw them one by one.

So you have to split your renderLayers() in that manner that not all layers are drawn at once (layers.forEach(this.renderLayer); ) but in a given order.

Pseudo Code:

```
scene.renderLayer(0);
scene.renderLayer(1);
player.Draw()
scene.renderLayer(2);
```

Comment: AHA! So simple.. Thank you!